# Why did the Python developers make Python 3 have more parentheses than Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For example in Python 3:

```
print("Hello world")
```

And in Python 2:

```
print "Hello world"
```

This makes me want to use Python 2 instead of Python 3, because it's simpler.

Comment: Because [PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/).

Comment: The `print` function is more powerful, too - take a look at its signature and options sometime. Doing those in Python2 was messier.

Comment: But he wouldn't be wrong if he sticks to python2 for now, since python3's adoption is going very slowly. That said, this is the first time I see someone actually questioning the 'user-friendliness' of a function...

Comment: Because of the print statement? That's the only reason you're basing your decision upon?

Comment: Well, that's the only one I know of cause I have not really messed with Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short simple answer:** `print` was made a function in Python 3 as @kojiro suggested.

Comment: Playing Devil's Advocate: `print` isn't a function in Python 2, so it's not inconsistent.

Comment: You mean they changed it so it could be a function?

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will choose this as the accepted answer (in 2 min.).

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/

> The following arguments for a print() function are distilled from a
>   python-3000 message by Guido himself:
>
> - print is the only application-level functionality that has a statement dedicated to it. Within Python's world, syntax is generally
>     used as a last resort, when something can't be done without help from
>     the compiler. Print doesn't qualify for such an exception.
> - At some point in application development one quite often feels the need to replace print output by something more sophisticated, like
>     logging calls or calls into some other I/O library. With a print()
>     function, this is a straightforward string replacement, today it is a
>     mess adding all those parentheses and possibly converting >>stream
>     style syntax.
> - Having special syntax for print puts up a much larger barrier for evolution, e.g. a hypothetical new printf() function is not too far
>     fetched when it will coexist with a print() function.
> - There's no easy way to convert print statements into another call if one needs a different separator, not spaces, or none at all. Also,
>     there's no easy way at all to conveniently print objects with some
>     other separator than a space.
> - If print() is a function, it would be much easier to replace it within one module (just def print(*args):...) or even throughout a
>     program (e.g. by putting a different function in **builtin**.print).
>     As it is, one can do this by writing a class with a write() method and
>     assigning that to sys.stdout -- that's not bad, but definitely a much
>     larger conceptual leap, and it works at a different level than print.

Answer (score 3):

In Python2, `print` is a statement but in Python3, `print` is a function

Try this

```
print(print("Welcome"))
```

in python 2, it will produce `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` but in python3 it will produce

```
Welcome
None
```

It means that, first the inner `print` is invoked which prints `Welcome` and it returns `None` to the outer `print` which simply prints it.